# Проблемы с логическим условием

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

При соблюдении этого и этих условий должно исчезать сообщение об ошибке, и кнопка ввода должна заблокироваться. А пир несоблюдении хотябы одного из этих условий обратное (кнопка заблокирована сообщение выводиться). Но этого не происходит , хотя вроди бы всё верно в коде.

Вот код самых условий :

```
var val = $("#phone").val();
var enable = true;
var valid = false;  

if (!val || val.replace(/\D/g, '').length < 13){ enable = false;}
if (codes[val.substr(5, 3)]){ valid = true;}
```

И код выполняющий их проверку:

```
     if (!enable || !valid) {
                    $('.error').text('Некорректный ввод');
                }else{
                    $('.error').text('');
                }

    if (valid && enable) { $("#call").removeAttr("disabled")};

     $("#call").Attr('disabled', !valid || !enable )
```

Код полностью : http://jsfiddle.net/0xL0fctq/57/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690330/jquery-keypress-backspace-wont-fire) описана аналогичная проблема с неперехватом backspace'а обработчиком события keypress. В качестве решения там предложено использовать keyup вместо keypress, т.е., в Вашем конкретном случае, вместо

```
$("#phone").keypress(function() {
    checkValid();
});
```

следует написать

```
$("#phone").keyup(function() {
    checkValid();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Заработало )

Answer (score 3):

У вас в номере **12** цифр,а не 13!

P.S. И поправьте ключи в массиве `codes`. Для всех элементов длина ключа должна быть 3 символа.

Comment: Исправил заработало но только когда вводишь номер. А когда удаляешь цифры то ни ошибка не вызывается и клавиша не блокируеться( Может есть каке-то событие которое отвечает за удаление символов ?

Comment: @Valeriy1996 Вот, [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690330/jquery-keypress-backspace-wont-fire), похоже, описан Ваш случай. Предлагается заменить `.keypress` на `.keyup`

Comment: @ Yaant Спасибо получилось. Добавьте ваш комментарий в ответы , я его добавлю в решение.